# angularjs radio button value check

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When I select the radio button nothing happens. Please chk my jsfiddle and help me to find what i did wrong.

```
var prnt = document.getElementById("prnt");
var app = angular.module('App', []);
app.controller('aCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.correctAns = function(){
if($scope.chk === "false"){
prnt.innerHTML+="working";

};
};

});
```

Here is my jsfiddle link

http://jsfiddle.net/rushdi1987/4d4tbext/5/

Comment: The name of your application in html is "App" and the name on your module is "app"

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you wanted to do?

```
var prnt = document.getElementById("prnt");
var app = angular.module('App', []);
app.controller('aCtrl', function ($scope) {

    $scope.chk = {
        val: false
    };

    $scope.check = function () {
        if ($scope.chk.val === false) {
            prnt.innerHTML = "True";
        }
    }
});
```